# weblogic tapestry issues

Tags: weblogic, tapestry, weblogic11g

My application using [tapestry](/questions/tagged/tapestry) 4.1.6 jar files deploys correctly in [weblogic](/questions/tagged/weblogic) 10.3.3.0. But at runtime, I am getting `NoSuchMethodException` from tapestry files.Same application works fine in weblogic 9. Any ideas?

### Error Log

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.TapestryKeyedObjectPool.assertOpen()V
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.TapestryKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(TapestryKeyedObjectPool.java:941)
    at org.apache.tapestry.pageload.PageSource.getPage(PageSource.java:176)
    at $IPageSource_12bf9e5c33a.getPage($IPageSource_12bf9e5c33a.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry.engine.RequestCycle.loadPage(RequestCycle.java:241)
    at org.apache.tapestry.engine.RequestCycle.getPage(RequestCycle.java:228)
    at org.apache.tapestry.engine.DirectService.service(DirectService.java:107)
    at $IEngineService_12bf9e5c3ad.service($IEngineService_12bf9e5c3ad.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.EngineServiceInnerProxy.service(EngineServiceInnerProxy.java:77)
    at org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.EngineServiceOuterProxy.service(EngineServiceOuterProxy.java:72)
    at org.apache.tapestry.engine.AbstractEngine.service(AbstractEngine.java:241)
    at org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.InvokeEngineTerminator.service(InvokeEngineTerminator.java:54)
    at $WebRequestServicer_12bf9e5c384.service($WebRequestServicer_12bf9e5c384.java)
    at $WebRequestServicer_12bf9e5c380.service($WebRequestServicer_12bf9e5c380.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.WebRequestServicerPipelineBridge.service(WebRequestServicerPipelineBridge.java:61)
    at $ServletRequestServicer_12bf9e5c366.service($ServletRequestServicer_12bf9e5c366.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry.request.DecodedRequestInjector.service(DecodedRequestInjector.java:55)
    at $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12bf9e5c362.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12bf9e5c362.java)
    at $ServletRequestServicer_12bf9e5c368.service($ServletRequestServicer_12bf9e5c368.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry.multipart.MultipartDecoderFilter.service(MultipartDecoderFilter.java:52)
    at $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12bf9e5c360.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12bf9e5c360.java)
    at $ServletRequestServicer_12bf9e5c368.service($ServletRequestServicer_12bf9e5c368.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.SetupRequestEncoding.service(SetupRequestEncoding.java:53)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd check to see if WebLogic 10.3 has a conflicting Tapestry JAR at the server class loader level.  If yes, you'll want to tell WebLogic to prefer the version of Tapestry that it finds using your application class loader.

See `<prefer-web-inf-classes>` in weblogic.xml:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html

Answer (score 0):

Note: Weblogic is often configured  by default, it filters javax.* package. (X Add J2EE libraries to buildpath)